# Prove that the edges of the cubic graph G cannot be coloured with three colours such that adjacent edges have different colours.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a connected cubic graph having a bridge $e = uv$

Prove that the edges of G cannot be coloured with three colours such that adjacent edges have different colours.

I started just by drawing the bridge between u and v and coloring it blue then drew two more edges incident with both u and v eventually showed it was true for a cubic graph on 4 vertices then moved onto the peterson graph and read there proof here [Prove that the Petersen graph does not have edge chromatic number = 3.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478998/prove-that-the-petersen-graph-does-not-have-edge-chromatic-number-3) but not sure how to generalize this result to the question at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the subgraph formed by just two of the colors, including the color used on the bridge $uv$.

It is two-regular, meaning that it is a union of cycles. In particular, $uv$ is part of a cycle, contradicting the assumption that it is a bridge.

Comment: Marvelous answer. P.S i hate you ^^